# golang regex get the string including the search character

Tags: regex, go

I am extracting a piece of string from a string (link):

```
https://arteptweb-vh.akamaihd.net/i/am/ptweb/100000/100000/100095-000-A_0_VO-STE%5BANG%5D_AMM-PTWEB_XQ.1V7rLEYkPH.smil/master.m3u8
```

The desired output should be **100000/100000/100095-000-A_**

I am using the Regex `^.*?(/[i,na,fm,d]([,/]?)(/am/ptweb/|.+=.+,))([^_]*).*?$` in Golang flavor and I can get only the group 4 with the folowing output 100000/100000/100095-000-A

However I want the underscore after A.

Bit stuck on this, any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you match the underscore in group 4? https://regex101.com/r/aYvN0t/1 Btw, I think this part should be a non capture group `(?:[id]|na|fm)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(/(i|na|fm|d)(/am/ptweb/|.+=.+,))([^_]*_?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x1ZaCf/1).

*Details*:

- `(/(i|na|fm|d)(/am/ptweb/|.+=.+,))` - Group 1:

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(i|na|fm|d)` - Group 2: `i`, `na`, `fm` or `d`
  - `(/am/ptweb/|.+=.+,)` - Group 3: `/amp/ptweb/` or one or more chars as many as possible (other than line break chars), `=`, one or more chars as many as possible (other than line break chars) and a `,` char
- `([^_]*_?)` - Group 4: zero or more chars other than `_` and then an optional `_`.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the underscore after the `A` like:

```
^.*?(/(?:[id]|na|fm)([,/]?)(/am/ptweb/|.+=.+,))([^_]*_).*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w2JB8u/1)

A few notes about the pattern that you tried:

- This notation is a character class `[i,na,fm,d]` which should be a grouping `(?:[id]|na|fm)`
- In this group `([,/]?)` you optionally capture either `,` or `/` so in theory it could match a string that has `/i//am/ptweb/`
- The last part `.*?$` does not have to be non greedy as it is the last part of the pattern
- This part `[^_]*` can also match spaces and newlines